# How can I save a file in specific folder?

Tags: 7, forms, files

I want to upload files to specific folders. How can I achieve this programatically.
 How can I modify below code such that upload_location should be dynamic.

```
    $form['document'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_validators' => array('file_validate_extensions' => array('xml')),
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#submit' => array('custom_document_submit'),
    );
```

Comment: How you wants to pass folder name? do you want to pass the folder name as a form element.

Comment: I have some folders in public://, so I am thinking to display all folder names in dropdown, then user can select the folder name and next upload option is there. When user selects folder and uploads files, it should go to that perticular folder. So how you will suggest me to do?

Answer (score 2):

In form submit action you can give the destination path.

```
function formname_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    $destination = $form_state['values']['foldername_name'];
    $validators = array();
    $file = file_save_upload('file', $validators, 'public://'.$destination);
}
```

More about file_save_upload get https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_save_upload/7.x.

more related links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253094/howto-drupal-file-upload-form

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there any way to pass dynamic folder name in the form element only.?

Comment: i think you want a input box for folder name right?

Comment: I have input box and i have one button, when I enter name and click a button, it will create a folder in public//:. But now i want to upload the files to the newly created folders.

Comment: are you creating folder on form submit button or another button present folder create.

Comment: for that form submit I am calling seperate submit function, not default form submit.